# Symfony $sf_params undefined

Tags: php, symfony1

I have just started working with Symfony. I downloaded the sf_sandbox and I am having trouble with $sf_params. When I try to use any methods on it, such as `$sf_params->has('status')` I get the error:

> Notice: Undefined variable: sf_params
>   in
>   /var/www/sf_sandbox/apps/frontend/modules/login/actions/actions.class.php
>   on line 14 Fatal error: Call to a
>   member function has() on a non-object
>   in
>   /var/www/sf_sandbox/apps/frontend/modules/login/actions/actions.class.php
>   on line 14

Here is the block:

```
public function executeIndex() {
    if ($sf_params->has('status') && $sf_params->has('message')) {  // <--line 14
        if ($sf_params->get('status') == 'failed') {
            $this->message = $sf_params->get('message');
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As The.Anti.9 stated, you must use $request when writing code inside an Action file.
You will need to replace your function definition as follows:

```
public function executeIndex(sfWebRequest $request) {
    $request->getParameter("status");
    ...
```

I hope that helps.

Edit: Just realized you answered your own question.

Answer (score 3):

The variable `$sf_params` is only available in the template. In the module the $request variable should be used.